# not working event setOnClickListener in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I am trying to use the setOnClickListener event but when I press the button the logs don't say anything

I would appreciate any help

Method used in the fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        var bnextButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton)
        var memeRandom: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.memeRandomView)
        bnextButton.setOnClickListener() {
            Log.d("Reference", "Working")
        }
        return view
    }
```

My layaout

```
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/memeRandomView"
      android:layout_width="385dp"
      android:layout_height="452dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
      android:src="@drawable/logo"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.578"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/nextButton"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
      android:text="Next"
      android:clickable="true"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/memeRandomView"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.434" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout as well?

Comment: If you wait a minute

Comment: your code is fine  , search for the "Reference" in logcat

Comment: Can you post layout file, or check yourself 1. Is your view shown? 2. do you have some view above your button? I this this is a reason. And one more thing, use onViewCreated(...) for working with view.